Is torch2.4.1 compatible with CUDA 12.5?
I locally installed my CUDA Toolkit 12.5. And everything went well (I can successfully call torch.cuda.is_available() and returns true) before I install torchvision with cmd conda install torchvision -c pytorch . After installing torchvision, I couldn't even import torch with error
OSError: [WinError 127] Error loading "D:\anaconda3\envs\pytorch2.4.1\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\torch_cuda.dll" or one of its dependencies

And pip list | findstr torch results in torch 2.4.1+cu124 and torchvision 0.19.1+cu124. How can I do to tackle this issue?
I wish there would exist a way that just requires downgrading the CUDA Toolkit version from 12.5 to 12.4 that works with torch and torchvision. Because I don't want to remove torch and re-download it and just want to keep the current version of torch and torchvision .

The modern standard pip version of pytorch you have installed includes all the CUDA runtime components it requires. There is no need to use an external CUDA toolkit. The problem you are seeing as nothing to do with the CUDA 12.5 toolkit you have installed, it is not being used for anything. You have somehow broken the internals of the torch and torchvision packages you are installed
